# Photo's import function

Tags: photos

Good day everyone!
I've come back to Linux distros and now I've started using Elementary for my main operating system. 
So, I have one question (deep looking into the "Photos" app isn't getting answers for me) about importing. 
I'm using for my photo-hobby Nikon's cameras with RAW (NEF) files and when I import them into my laptop, the application automating convert my photos to JPEG (like and for all my collection, when I've moved to a new system, this app convert ALL my RAWs to JPEG). How I can import only RAW from my flash-card without converting? And how turnoff automatic import?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, on my PC Photos doesn't auto-import anything when I connect my camera. At the same time I couldn't find a preference inside the app which could be responsible for that behavior, let alone 'Do not convert my RAWs into JPGs please' option.

There's a preference called 'Watch library for new files' though, so try turning that off and see if it fixes the auto-import issue. If it doesn't, try your luck and [report](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues) that to the eOS devs.